# How does Python's seek function work?

Tags: python, seek

If I have some file-like object and do the following:

```
F = open('abc', 'r')
...
loc = F.tell()
F.seek(loc-10)
```

What does seek do? Does is start at the beginning of the file and read `loc-10` bytes? Or is it smart enough just to back up 10 bytes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is OS- and libc-specific. the `file.seek()` operation is delegated to the `fseek(3)` C call for actual OS-level files.

Comment: So is this platform and implementation dependent?

Comment: Yes, with the implementation split up between the libc and OS.

Comment: So is it possible/easy to do this without starting at the beginning of the file?

Comment: In most platforms, the file position is just a number stored in the file handle table; there's no physical drive seeking going on. So there's no reason to "just back up 10 bytes". When you do the next read or write, that's where the libc/OS/filesystem can be smart and realize you're reading out of a block that's still in cache and not read at all, or reading the previous block so it only needs to seek one block (not that the distinction matters on a modern drive anyway—the previous virtual block could be on, say, a different physical drive in your LVM array…).

Comment: Also, note that this is an `fseek`, not an `lseek`, which means there's a `FILE*` managed by libc on top of whatever the OS has, and the `FILE*` probably has its own position and buffer, so it may not even have to go to the OS/filesystem for the subsequent read.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Python 2.7's docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek):

> `file.seek(offset[, whence])`
>
> Set the file’s current position, like stdio‘s fseek(). The whence
>   argument is optional and defaults to os.SEEK_SET or 0 (absolute file
>   positioning); other values are os.SEEK_CUR or 1 (seek relative to the
>   current position) and os.SEEK_END or 2 (seek relative to the file’s
>   end).

Say you would want to go 10 bytes back relative to your position:

```
file.seek(-10, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be smart enough to just back up 10 bytes, but I suppose that the details really depend on the filesystem/OS/runtime library you're using.

Note that if you just want to back up 10 bytes, there's no need for `tell`.

```
F.seek(-10,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This is a much simpler implementation than I gave as my example.

Answer (score 3):

```
file.seek() set the current read/write position.
file.tell() Returns the file's current position.
```

So when you did `**loc = F.tell()**` you are store the current file position to the **loc** variable.

And `**file.seek()**` takes two arguments `**file.seek(offset, from)**`

So you need to define from where to you want offset the file. `**from**` takes one of following values **0,1,2** (0 = beginning, 1 = current, 2 = end)

So that's how it's work.

Answer (score -4):

according to the documentation, you need to do `f.seek(offset, from_what)`, or in your case, `F.seek(-10, loc)`

your example should work, but this is more explicit

Comment: This is quite misleading.  This answer only works if `loc` is 1.