# python seek() from beginning or from current position?

Tags: python, seek

I'm dealing with a large file (>500GB, few columns but several lines), and I need to get some lines from there. I have this list of start byte and endbytes (measured from the beginning of the file) for the parts that I need, something like:

```
A,0,500
B,1089,4899
```

Here's the thing: I have to do this around 1.2 M times. Which is better for performance: always starting from the beginning of the document, or counting from current position? So it would be something like:

```
with open(large_file, 'r') as f:
    for start_byte, end_byte in byte_list:
        f.seek(start_byte) # always start from beginning of file
        chunk_str = f.read(end_byte-start_byte)
```

or

```
with open(large_file, 'r') as f:
    current_pos = 0
    for start_byte, end_byte in byte_list:
        f.seek(start_byte - current_pos, 1) # seek from current position
        chunk_str = f.read(end_byte-start_byte)
        current_pos = end_byte
```

Or does it even matter at all? I've read [How does Python's seek function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278748/how-does-pythons-seek-function-work) but I'm not technically proficient enough to understand how this would affect reading very large text files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python's seek function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278748/how-does-pythons-seek-function-work)

Comment: It doesn't matter at all, the stdlib converts it in a simple operation.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I read that too, but it's more technical than I could understand. Anyway thanks for all those who answered so far. I'd go with the simpler version then (just start from the beginning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the absolute form, since an absolute byte offset is what you have. The work of actually *reading* from the correct location after using `seek` is buried in the file system driver used by your OS. `seek` itself does little more than set a variable.

You would use `f.seek(d, 1)` if you don't already know your current position, but know that you need to skip ahead by `d` bytes.